# C# Control Add/Remove Feeze

Tags: c#

This code is Error.

```
removeCount = this.cameras.RemoveAll(delegate (DalsaCamera camera)
{
    bool dead = camera.isDead();

    if (dead)
    {
        camera.destroyObjects();
        camera.disposeObjects();

        if (controls.Contains(camera.ImageView))
        {
             this.controls.Remove(camera.ImageView);
             camera.ImageView.Dispose();
        }
     }
     return dead;
});
```

```
public void destroyObjects()
{
    if (m_Xfer != null && m_Xfer.Initialized)
        m_Xfer.Destroy();
    if (m_View != null && m_View.Initialized)
        m_View.Destroy();
    if (m_Buffers != null && m_Buffers.Initialized)
        m_Buffers.Destroy();
    if (m_AcqDevice != null && m_AcqDevice.Initialized)
        m_AcqDevice.Destroy();
}
```

This Camera is DalsaCamera. m_Xfer, m_Buffers, m_AcqDevice is SaperaLT Library.

Image Class View is PictureBox View.

Why is Freeze happening?

Comment: `Freeze happening over there` what does it mean?

Comment: this.controls.Remove(camera.ImageView); 
-> This line is Freeze.

Comment: I don't know the `DalsaCamera` class, but the faulty part may be you're disposing the object before accessing the property.

Comment: What happened when you started your debugger and debugged it?

Comment: Visual Studio has two helpful tabs: Parallel Stacks and Tasks. When your app freezes - you can pause debug and see what tasks executing. Probably there are deadlock. Now there is not enough information in your question to answer what is the reason - there is not enough real code that is involved at the time of the freeze